# Referencing, when you can assume that readers and you know "what you talk about"? Is it unnecessary?

Tags: citations

Referencing, when you can assume that readers and you know "what you talk about"? Is it unnecessary?

I.e. if I can be sure that any reader of my paper that's of a sufficient professional level, should agree on what I'm saying, then is it necessary to reference in order to "prove a view"?

This applies to e.g. definitions or methodologies or such. For example, if I write a paper on image segmentation that's read by people who also study image segmentation or are experienced in it, then would it be unnecessary to cite "elementary texts" on something that may be considered "basic knowledge in image segmentation".